# Finding common format in set of strings

Tags: database, string, text

I need to find common format in a set of strings. Ie. we have a couple of strings which represents same data type but they don't have standardized form (format).

For example -- we have a following set of phone numbers

```
600123456  
(600)111222
+1600333444
600 654 456
```

All of them represent the same kind of information (a phone number) but every one of them is stored in a different format. I can't really use anything like Levenshtein distance because the string can be very different but still represent same type.

This phone numbers should be transformed to something like

```
600123456  
600111222
1600333444
600654456
```

How can I know if the set of strings represents the same kind of data? How can I extract this data to the simplest possible form?

Comment: Your first question makes it hard to understand what you are looking for: are all the values in the same column in a table? Are they randomly distributed in documents and you are looking to classify by a set of types?